# Lithium/Apache on Mac : can't access to the view

Tags: lithium

I have installed Lithium and tested on Mac.

I can't access to the views that i defined. I can only access to the index file.

My simple project is firstLithium. I set it in /Library/Webserver/Documents
In this project, i create 1 view named posts. Here after is the content of my MVC.

**models/Posts.php** :

```
    <?php
    namespace app\models;
    class Posts extends \lithium\data\Model {
    }
    ?>
```

**views/posts/index.html.php** :

### Lithium is less dense than ium.

**controllers/PostsController.php**

```
    <?php
    namespace app\controllers;
    class PostsController extends \lithium\action\Controller {
        public function index() {
            return array('foo' => 'bar', 'title' => 'Posts');        
        }   
          public function add() {
        }
    }
    ?>
```

From web browser :

- localhost/firstLithium : it works well
- localhost/firstLithium/posts : it doesn't work

Not Found
The requested URL /firstLithium/posts was not found on this server.
The same example can run on ubuntu, but not on Mac. Can i help you to run it on Mac. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely looks like a problem with your web server settings, and not Lithium.
Try this [guide](http://lithify.me/docs/manual/configuration/servers/apache.wiki) and if the problem persist, feel free to ping me in #li3 IRC channel.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled, for Apache. I'm not sure what the command is, for a Mac, but on Linux, it's:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```